# Resizing array, does this code influence it badly in any way?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've seen bunch of tutorials and threads, but no-one does this to resize an array. My question is, whether this affects bad something in my program or is there better way to resize it?

```
//GOAL:Array  to become {1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9}
    int size=9;
    int array[size] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for (int i = 2; i < 8; ++i)
        array[i] = array[i + 1];

//ARRAY IS NOW{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9}
//GOAL: TO DELETE THAT LAST 9 FROM ARRAY
    size=8;
    array[size];
//IT SHOULD BE {1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9} now, but does it effect my program in any negative context?
```

Comment: arrays are not meant to be resized. use  e.g, std::vector if you want to resize.

Comment: Also, `size` is not even a compile time constant, so this doesn't even compile.

Comment: Why do you think, that last line would resize an array?

Comment: @MikeMB - My int size at the beginning of a program is 9, and it defines length of an array.
After that I did size--(which is now 8) and again defined lenght of array with that same size.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: g++ and clang++ will with default settings ;)

Comment: @Malcom98. Why do you think that `array[size];` **defines** an array? Since, it doesn't..

Comment: @Malcom98.: And why do you think `array[size]` has a different effect than `array[i+1]`? A few lines above? In short: You can't resize arrays period and `array[size]` just selectes the element at position `size`

Comment: C++ does not work this way. You are missing some basic C++ knowledge. The first `for` loop is even undefined behavior, and a potential crash.

Comment: [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b416ed0af4a3aa93). When you do `array[size]`, the compiler thinks you are _indexing_ it, not resizing.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Why should it be undefined behavior? (Although it doesn't make a lot of sense)

Comment: @Malcom98. That's what's `std::vector<int>` is for.

Comment: @user0042 - Thanks for advice. On my way. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int array[size]` declares an array of size elements.
Outside of a declaration, `array[size]` access element size in array. It does not resize the array.  If you do something like that without changing the value of size, it actually tries to access the element *after*  the last element in the array; not a good idea. In this case, since you changed size to be one less than the original, it accesses the last element of the array, which is safe but does not do what you want.

You can not resize an array in C/C++ that is declared on the stack (one allocated on the heap with malloc could be reallocated to a different size, but you'd have trouble copying it as the newly allocated array of the new size is possibly at a completely different memory location; you'd have to save the old one, allocate a new one of the new size, copy the elements you want, and then free the old one.)

If you want something resizeable, you are in C++; use a container (vector, for example, but pick the one that most suits your needs).

And....I just saw arnav-borborah's comment; don't know how I missed that.  You can't even declare the array like that, as size is not a compile time constant.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got it."It actually tries to access the element after the last element in the array."
That's what I needed.
Alright, that was just a question because I was wondering whether should I learn vectors. Thank you!

Comment: No, it just accesses the last element, since 8 is the last index

Comment: @ArnavBorborah, right, because the value of "size" was changed.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

Until `size` variable is not [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), this

```
int size=9;
int array[size] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

is [Variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which is not part of [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) standard, only extension of some compilers.

Also automatic arrays are not resizeable, they have fixed size since declaration until they goes out of scope.

You should use some STL container, like `std::array`, `std::vector`.

`std::array` needs to know size at compile time, so there is *the best* approach, `std::vector`, which is easy to use and resizeable.

```
// #include<vector>

std::vector<int> array { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 }; // Uniform initialization

// Remove last element
array.pop_back();  // 'array' has now only 8 elements (1..8)
```

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned in comments, if you want to remove *n-th* element in vector, you may do

```
array.erase(array.begin()+n);
```

and job is done.

Comment: In this case the OP can use `array.erase(array.begin()+2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hugely. say if you have a payload of 1GB and you Array.Resize the destination array in chunks of 10k then most of your application CPU and wait states will be resizing that array.
If you pre-allocate the array to 1GB, populating that array will be orders of magnitude faster. This is because every time you use Array.Resize.
The computer needs to move that memory in its entirety to another location in memory just to add the extra length you resized it by.
But of cause if you are dealing with very small arrays. This effect is not noticeable.